# Can I consider this as a truncated normal distribution?

Tags: truncation, truncated-normal-distribution

I have a variable whose maximum value is fixed (maximum number of days in the observation period). In some plots, the histogram of the log-transformed variable peaks near the maximum, but not *at* the maximum, like the red curve here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xZDzNXD2qdGN8Fdf1B_2SSUcgrmSdYEy

I'm looking for the best way to represent the difference between the blue and red curves. It's clear from the graph that the red curve peaks more towards the maximum, and the blue curve further less, and that's what I want to emphasize. For a single number representation, I think the mean can do for the blue curve, but I'm pretty sure it won't accurate reflect the "typical" value of the red curve. I'm thinking of two options:

1. boxplot (basically, median and quartiles)
2. assume this is a truncated normal, and estimate the mean and standard deviation

Which is the more reasonable one, in this case, given that there is a hard maximum value for the variable?

Comment: could you imbed the image in the question, it helps with readability. see https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting